# admin template menu not allowint to click on other links when it is active for a blaock

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Hi i'm using admin template in codeigniter and created a menu, this is working for one level links properly but when i click on links in the list pages then this menu not allowing to click on the menu links.

sample code

```
 <ul class="nav side-menu">
     <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='dashboard'){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
      <ul class="nav child_menu"<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='dashboard'){echo 'style="display-block"';}?> >
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/dashboard">Dashboard </a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>                      
     <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='document' || $this->uri->segment(2)=='field' ){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> Application<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
       <ul class="nav child_menu" <?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='document' || $this->uri->segment(2)=='field' ){echo 'style="display:block"';}?>>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/document">Applicant List</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/document/add">New Case Entry</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/document/uploadbulk">Bulk Data Upload</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

[image]

when i click on documents or other parent links it is not opening.

Comment: you mind sharing screenshots of your views of what is going on and what you intend to do. Will be easier to look at it for us.

Comment: if only this link is not working it means there is no data under it but if all drop downs are not working, it means your js is not working. See the path of your jquery

Comment: I have created a boiler plate in CI for Admin panel. See https://github.com/malikmudassar/CI_admin it might help